# How to give custom name when printjs library used

Tags: printjs

I am able to do print functionality using printjs but i want to give custom name which i failed to do it.Any suggestions would help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

Print.js has a property named `documentTitle` where you can pass a document title when printing html, json and images. It also has a header option as well if that's what you are looking for. Take a look at the lib api options here:

https://printjs.crabbly.com/#configuration